# dividing or multiplying integers result in 0.0000 every time

Tags: c, integer

when i try print preTopping the answer is always 0.0000 even after adding (float) beforehand

```
int length, width;
printf("Please enter your pizza's length (cm): ");
scanf(" %d", &length);
printf("Please enter your pizzas width (cm): ");
scanf(" %d", &width);

float preTopping, postTopping=0;
preTopping = ((length * width) / (40 * 40)) * 60;
printf("%f", preTopping);
```

Comment: `((length * width) / (40 * 40)) * 60` is an integer calculation (since all values are integers). It doesn't matter that you assign it into a `float`. You can use a cast (`(float)(length * width)`) to make one of the operands (and the whole calculation) a floating point one.

Comment: @wohlstad i see.... i tried before to put (float) over the entire expression and it didnt work. i guess it had to be more specific towards (length * width)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this expression:

```
((length * width) / (40 * 40)) * 60;
```

All operands have type `int`.  This means that integer division is done, and integer division truncates any fractional part.  So if `length * width` is less than 1600, the result of the division will be 0 since that's the integer part of the result.

If you want to use floating point division, you need to cast at least one operand of the division to a floating point type:

```
preTopping = ((float)(length * width) / (40 * 40)) * 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a common beginner mistake to think that an expression is carried out on the same type as the result is assigned to. That is not true; what type you happen to have on the left side of the `=` doesn't matter the slightest. The sub expression `((length * width) / (40 * 40)) * 60` is calculated on `int` types no matter.

Note that constants such as `40` has a type too and it is `int`. Unless you write `40.0f` = float or `40.0` = double.

Best practices:

- Never mix integer and floating point types in the same expression. It's very easy to create bugs that way.
- You probably shouldn't use `float` at all, but `double`, assuming you are programming on a x86 PC. There are a few specialized uses for `float` but they are limited to microcontroller programming of Cortex M4 and similar devices with a single precision FPU. If that's the CPU you are using, then don't use `float`.

One fix in case you need to use integer variables in the expression is to cast them to the desired floating point type:

```
double preTopping = ((double)length * (double)width) / (40.0 * 40.0) * 60.0;
```

In this expression, every single operand is of type `double` and no implicit conversions are taking place. That's good, rugged, maintainable code.

---

Sloppy, brittle code is another possibility:

```
// BAD CODE
double preTopping = ((double)length * width) / (40 * 40) * 60;
```

This works too, but it's one of those "being too clever" solutions that should be avoided like the plague. This code relies on implicit type promotion (specifically something called *the usual arithmetic conversions*), namely that in case we have two operands of the `*` operator, `(double)length` and an `int width`, the `width` parameter will get implicitly promoted to `double`, the calculation will get carried out on `double` and the resulting of the sub expression is `double`.

And so this implicit promotion escalates throughout the whole expression. In this case we have `*` and `/` with same operator precedence but left-to-right associativity, meaning `((double)length * width)` will get converted to `double` first. Then the result of that is `double` and we get `"result" / 1600` where the `1600` operand is of type `int` (since 40 and 40 were `int`). One by one the operands get implicitly converted to `double`.

However, in case someone decides to maintain the code (it happens!), shuffle around the operators or add a higher precedence operator somewhere, it could cause havoc.

Best practices:

- Avoid writing code relying on implicit type promotions.
- Writing code as "smart" as possible is in fact dumb. Harder to read, harder to maintain, harder to troubleshoot. A wise quote by the C programming legend Brian Kernighan:

  *"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."*